# Using fetch() to post a form data to a database(mongodb) and rendering the body of the form in a view(EJS preferably)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, post, fetch, mongoose-schema

Basically what i want to do is SUBMIT a form which contains input values for a ride request [creating a ride request] and immediately after clicking submit,i want the inputed data to display on the same page(using EJS preferably) with all i have inputed [i.e as an actual ride request].

Note, i want to do it in a real time front end--back end environment where as i hit submit,it gets saved to the mongodb atlas database and still do the [above explained].

please anything to help would be appreciated, i am building a carpooling app and i have been stucked for days.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to set up a RESTful api on the back-end. Have you done this?
You then use the fetch api to display the data. If you provide the restful paths, I can help..

Comment: yes i have done that and if you wouldn't mind we can connect and i would show you my full code, I use ZOOM, ANYDESK and I can download anything you convinient with. please, i need help ASAP. Thanks so much

Comment: i am so patiently waiting for you, anyway, anytime you want the session, just say it..i have been stucked for days, seeing your comments saying you can do it kinda calm my nerves..Thanks

Comment: Yes sure..where can we keep up aside here..I am on twitter as @ridiselassie or where would you prefer we chat ? you know it takes time to get replies from here, like I was literally refreshing this page every minute to get your reply, I was scared I lost you already..Thanks

Comment: fine, I have trying to emails my codes to you through gmail but it won't let me because i attached all of the codes in a zip file, if you don't mind, how about you go through the codes in my github repository,i dropped the link to it in your email already...Thanks

Comment: i have been waiting on a reply from you...hope you are fine ? and i was going to suggest you can just set up a mini RESTful API of your own to demonstrate what i want to resolve and then I can just adapt that to my code myself, just incase my code is confusing you.